# Getting much less CPU utilisation while configuring Jmeter sampler through implementation by httpclient4 than implementation by Java

Tags: jmeter, implementation

While running JMeter execution having sampler with implementation httpclient4 causing less CPU utilisation than executing with implementation by Java. Can anyone suggest why, and which one is recommended for better performance test?

Comment: Please provide more information including actual and expected results, code samples would also be great where applicable. This question is very open-ended without additional information.

Comment: While sampler in my JMeter suit having implementation option as JAVA, on execution the average CPU Utilization was coming as 30-40%. After changing the implementation of the samplers as HttpClient4, the CPU utilization is decreased to 20-30% and now not exceeding more than 10% on average, on the same application. Although I came to know, httpclient4 is recommended, but I have a doubt whether it triggers more requests concurrently or not. Think time and other parameters are set as it is before.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Client implementation uses [thread pool pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool) therefore when connection is not used anymore it's returned to the pool and when the next thread needs a connection it just takes one from the pool.

With Java implementation there is no control on how connections are re-used, it's for JVM to decide whether to keep the connection or to close it. Establishing a connection is quite an "expensive" operation therefore my expectation is that you're seeing discrepancies due to this.

It's only a "blind shot", there are too many unknown factors, you can use a [profiler tool](https://www.baeldung.com/java-profilers) to compare both and see what exactly is causing CPU load.

Java implementation has some more limitations, for example:

1. Doesn't support [multiple client side certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-multiple-certificates-when-load-testing-secure-websites) (aliases)
2. Doesn't support virtual hosts
3. Supports only following [HTTP methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods): GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE and TRACE

So I would recommend going for HTTPClient where possible (and in fact it's JMeter's default setting)